# Xml Validation error: validating against empty schema set

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

1. I am getting the error

   > The XmlSchemaSet on the document is either null or has no schemas in it. Provide schema information before calling Validate.

   But I have the schema file located in the location specified: `C:\InvSchema.xsd`

   There is no specific namespace passed, so I set that to empty.

   So, why am I getting this error?
2. I also need to know if the xml schema was successfully validated, but the validate function does no return a boolean value confirming it.

   How can I get that value from `InvImp.Validate(evtHandler)`?

Below is the code:

```
 Private Function ValidateSchema() As Boolean
            Try
                Dim settings As XmlReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings()
                settings.Schemas.Add("", "C:\InvSchema.xsd")
                settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema
                Dim evtHandler As ValidationEventHandler = New ValidationEventHandler(AddressOf ValidationEventHandler)
                Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(_fileName, settings)
                Dim InvImp As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
                InvImp.Validate(evtHandler)              
                ValidateSchema = True
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
                ValidateSchema = False
            End Try
        End Function


Shared Sub ValidationEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ValidationEventArgs)
        Select Case e.Severity
            Case XmlSeverityType.Error
                Library.Log("Schema validation failed error " & e.Message, LogType.ERRORLOG, ImportType.InvcIMP)
            Case XmlSeverityType.Warning
                Library.Log("Schema validation warning " & e.Message, LogType.EVENTLOG, ImportType.InvcIMP)
        End Select            
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems. The event handler isn't getting added properly and the xmlReader should be used to validate instead of a separate XmlDocument object:

```
Private Function ValidateSchema() As Boolean
    Try
        Dim settings As XmlReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings()
        settings.Schemas.Add("", "C:\InvSchema.xsd")
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema
        AddHandler settings.ValidationEventHandler, AddressOf ValidationEventHandler
        Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(_fileName, settings)

        Do While reader.Read
            'Triggers validation'
        Loop

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
    Return _valid
End Function
```

You also should set a member level boolean (_valid) in your event handler. The event handler will get called for every schema violation found.